# error installling feature Opendaylight Oxygen release?

Tags: opendaylight

I downloaded the pre-build **".tar"** version of Open-daylight Oxygen release. When I try to install the **dlux** feature using **feature:install** command, I get the following error.

dluxapps-topology error:

```
Error executing command: Exception in org.opendaylight.controller.config.manager.impl.osgi.ConfigManagerActivator.stop() of bundle org.opendaylight.controller.config-manager.
```

dluxapps-application error:

```
19:32:19.530 [Refresh Thread: Equinox Container: d3f0af16-e328-4ecd-927f-ddb53597d0d5] ERROR org.opendaylight.controller.config.manager.impl.osgi.ConfigManagerActivator - Error starting config manager
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BundleContext is no longer valid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.checkValid(BundleContextImpl.java:984) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:463) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:482) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:999) [?:?]
    at org.opendaylight.controller.config.manager.impl.osgi.mapping.RefreshingSCPModuleInfoRegistry.<init>(RefreshingSCPModuleInfoRegistry.java:47) [112:org.opendaylight.controller.config-manager:0.8.0]
    at org.opendaylight.controller.config.manager.impl.osgi.ConfigManagerActivator.start(ConfigManagerActivator.java:61) [112:org.opendaylight.controller.config-manager:0.8.0]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1) [?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.start(ModuleContainer.java:736) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.applyDelta(ModuleContainer.java:727) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.resolveAndApply(ModuleContainer.java:497) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.resolve(ModuleContainer.java:443) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.refresh(ModuleContainer.java:987) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerWiring.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1368) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerWiring.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230) [?:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340) [?:?]
19:32:19.580 [Blueprint Extender: 1] ERROR io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - LEAK: HashedWheelTimer.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. Enable advanced leak reporting to find out where the leak occurred. To enable advanced leak reporting, specify the JVM option '-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=advanced' or call ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel() See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DLUX subproject in ODL currently is no longer actively maintained by anyone.  It was therefore actually removed in the current dev release cycle (current master, upcoming Fluorine).  It's not suprising to see that it actually was already broken in Oxygen.  If you / your organization has an active interest in DLUX, you would most probably be very welcome to step as the new active maintainer to fix it and keep it up to date... ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, Is there any alternative tool to check the topology and explore the yang modules.

Comment: Not that I know of, but perhaps others who reads this can comment. Or you can try to open a new question. But have you considered just directly using the RESTCONF HTTP REST API to read the YANG data store for what interests you?