# OpenDaylight Oxygen: No DLUX app?

Tags: opendaylight

I just installed the new Oxygen version of OpenDaylight. However, the feature called Dlux, which provide a GUI, is not available.

According to the official [documentation](http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-oxygen/user-guide/using-the-opendaylight-user-interface-(dlux).html), the commande `feature:install odl-dlux-core` should install it, but it didn't exist.

So, has the feature another name for installation, or is it not implemented for Oxygen yet?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error installling feature Opendaylight Oxygen release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931720/error-installling-feature-opendaylight-oxygen-release)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately dlux no longer has any contributors/maintainers so has been dropped from the upstream releases (although I thought this was only done on the current master branch...).

Comment: Ok, is there any alternatives ? I saw their was another GUI called NeXT but it is not available as well.

Comment: Tom, I also didn't realize we removed it from Oxygen, but I checked and it's not there. Nakrule, no I don't think there are any publicly available GUI frontends for OpenDaylight at this point.

Comment: Jamo, I didn't know it was removed from Oxygen either. The NeXT project was abandoned as well. We would welcome anyone who wants to reboot and maintain dlux or NeXT.

Comment: They are actually using pre-release Fluorine, see the OPs comment about version 9.0.

Answer (score 2):

I have downloaded both Oxygen and Oxygen SR1 and I see dlux in both:

https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.release/org/opendaylight/integration/karaf/0.8.0/karaf-0.8.0.zip
https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.release/org/opendaylight/integration/karaf/0.8.1/karaf-0.8.1.zip

```
opendaylight-user@root>feature:install odl-dlux-core
opendaylight-user@root>
```

Can you please verify you are using right download links?

Comment: Mine is 0.9.0. It was downloaded throught DevStack (a tools to install an OpenStack cloud, which installed and configured OpenDaylight as well in my case).

Comment: So you're actually using master then, pre-release Fluorine is major version 9.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to ODL and have worked my way down from Al to O in order to follow several how-to's. I am also looking for DLUX-based modules; two years ago this question was asked and it applies to me today! I came across the following in O version 0.8.4; I hope it helps you.

```
opendaylight-user@root>feature:list | grep odl-dlux

odl-dluxapps-yangutils                           │ 0.7.4            │          │ Uninstalled │ odl-dluxapps-yangutils                           │ ODL :: dluxapps :: odl-dluxapps-yangutils


odl-dluxapps-nodes                               │ 0.7.4            │ x        │ Started     │ odl-dluxapps-nodes                               │ ODL :: dluxapps :: odl-dluxapps-nodes


odl-dluxapps-yangman                             │ 0.7.4            │          │ Uninstalled │ odl-dluxapps-yangman                             │ ODL :: dluxapps :: odl-dluxapps-yangman


odl-dluxapps-yangui                              │ 0.7.4            │ x        │ Started     │ odl-dluxapps-yangui                              │ ODL :: dluxapps :: odl-dluxapps-yangui


odl-dlux-core                                    │ 0.7.4            │          │ Started     │ odl-dlux-0.7.4                                   │ Opendaylight dlux minimal feature


odl-dluxapps-topology                            │ 0.7.4            │          │ Started     │ odl-dluxapps-topology                            │ ODL :: dluxapps :: odl-dluxapps-topology

odl-dluxapps-yangvisualizer                      │ 0.7.4            │          │ Uninstalled │ odl-dluxapps-yangvisualizer                      │ ODL :: dluxapps :: odl-dluxapps-yangvisualizer

odl-dluxapps-applications                        │ 0.7.4            │          │ Uninstalled │ odl-dluxapps-applications                        │ ODL :: dluxapps :: odl-dluxapps-applications

opendaylight-user@root>
```